# Append divs to another div after its has already been appended to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My program is a game that begins with 4 playable characters each in their own div with class `charContainer`, these 4 divs are in a container with class `character`. When the player picks a character by clicking on them, it moves it to a container with class `your`. After that the remaining unchosen characters in the container `characters` move to another div container called `enemies`. This div would have the remaining 3 unclicked divs moved to it. After this, the player selects an opponent. I am trying to move the selected opponent to the div container called `opponent`, but it keeps getting appended to the `your` container. I tried removing the class name `charContainer` and adding class `foes` and it still does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.charContainer').on('click', function() {
    $('#your').append($(this));
    $('.characters>.charContainer').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('charContainer').addClass('foes');
      $('#enemies').append($(this));
    })
    $('.characters').remove();
  })

  $('.foes').on('click', function() {
    $('#opponent').append($(this));
    // $(this).appendTo('#opponent');
    $(this).addClass('defender');
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="characters">
  <div class="charContainer darth">
    <h2 id="c1"></h2>
    <img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
    <p id="c1hp" data-hp="120"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer luke">
    <h2 id="c2"></h2>
    <img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg">
    <p id="c2hp" data-hp="100"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer won">
    <h2 id="c3"></h2>
    <img class="obi" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg">
    <p id="c3hp" data-hp="150"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer maul">
    <h2 id="c4"></h2>
    <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
    <p id="c4hp" data-hp="180"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="your">
  <h2>Your Character</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="enemies">
  <h2>Enemies</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="fightSection">
  <h2>Fight Section</h2>
  <button id="attack" class="attk">
    <h1>Attack</h1>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="opponent">
  <h2>Opponent</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
```

After removing the `charContainer` class and adding the `foes` class, the `onclick` function for `foes` still sends it to the `your` div even though I got rid of `charContainer`. I need it to go to the `opponent` div.

Answer (score 2):

Call `.off("click")`

```
$(".characters>.charContainer").off("click")
```

within `.characters>.charContainer` `click` handler to detach `click` from `.charContainer` elements.

Use event delegation, `.one()` at `#enemies` element, if only one `.foes` element should be append to `#opponenent` element

```
$('#enemies').one('click', ".foes", function() {})
```

when attaching `click` to `#enemies` element for handler to be called when elements having dynamically added `className` `foes` are clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.charContainer').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#your").append(this);
    $('.characters>.charContainer')
    .off("click")
      .each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('charContainer')
          .addClass('foes');
        $('#enemies').append(this);
      })

    $('.characters').remove();
  })

  $('#enemies').one('click', ".foes", function() {
    $('#opponent').append($(this));
    // $(this).appendTo('#opponent');
    $(this).addClass('defender');
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="characters">
  <div class="charContainer darth">
    <h2 id="c1"></h2>
    <img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg" alt="vader">
    <p id="c1hp" data-hp="120"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer luke">
    <h2 id="c2"></h2>
    <img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg" alt="luke">
    <p id="c2hp" data-hp="100"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer won">
    <h2 id="c3"></h2>
    <img class="obi" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg" alt="obiwan">
    <p id="c3hp" data-hp="150"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer maul">
    <h2 id="c4"></h2>
    <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png" alt="maul">
    <p id="c4hp" data-hp="180"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="your">
  <h2>Your Character</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="enemies">
  <h2>Enemies</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="fightSection">
  <h2>Fight Section</h2>
  <button id="attack" class="attk">
    <h1>Attack</h1>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="opponent">
  <h2>Opponent</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue is that you are adding your "character" `click` event listener to each actual `<div class="charContainer">` with the code:

```
$('.charContainer').on('click', function(){...
```

Then, once you had moved the `charContainer` divs to `enemies` those event listeners were still on the `charContainer` divs.  Thus, when you clicked on one, it was moved to the `your` div. You can solve this by either removing the listener using [`.off('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) on each div, or using event delegation. In the code below, I chose event delegation.

In addition, you were trying to add listeners to any `.foes` immediately after adding the other listeners, but before the user clicked on anything.  At the time the code:

```
$('.foes').on('click', function() {...
```

was executed, there was nothing in your document that matched the selector `'.foes'`. Thus, no event listeners were added.

To solve this, I changed:

In your HTML:

```
<div class="characters">
```

to

```
<div id="characters">
```

You are using `characters` to uniquely identify that specific div, not to groups one or more elements.  Thus, for the way that you are using it, `characters` is more appropriate as an `id` than a `class`.

In your JavaScript, the primary changes are to change your event listeners to be on the container div elements, but to only execute your handler when the element matches the selector `'.charContainer'`.  For example,

```
$('#characters').on('click', '.charContainer', function(e) {...
```

adds a click event handler to all elements which match the selector `'#characters'`. That is the div which contains the characters which you are selecting from for `your` character.  The second argument to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) tells jQuery to only execute your handler when the event target (`e.target`) matches the selector `.charContainer`.

Your other event handler, for `foes`, I changed to:

```
$('#enemies').on('click', '.foes', function(e) {
```

As with the `characters` listener, this uses event delegation to have this event listener on your `<div id="enemies">`, but only execute your handler when the event target matches the selector `'.foes'`.

I also changed your use of `this` to `e.target` within your event handlers when you were using it to refer to the target of the event. While your use was fine, when using functions within an event handler which change the value of `this` ([`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), here) I find that using the explicit event target, provides for more maintainable code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#characters').on('click', '.charContainer', function(e) {
    $('#your').append(e.target);
    $('#characters>.charContainer').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('charContainer').addClass('foes');
      $('#enemies').append($(this));
    })
    $('#characters').remove();
  })

  $('#enemies').on('click', '.foes', function(e) {
    $('#opponent').append(e.target);
    $(e.target).addClass('defender');
    $('#enemies').remove(); //Added this to match action on picking character.
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="characters">
  <!-- Added  style="display: inline-block;" to characters because that looks
       better in a snippet-->
  <div class="charContainer darth" style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2 id="c1"></h2>
    <img class="vade" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5g5.png">
    <p id="c1hp" data-hp="120"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer luke" style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2 id="c2"></h2>
    <img class="skywalker" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7VCH.png">
    <p id="c2hp" data-hp="100"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer won" style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2 id="c3"></h2>
    <img class="obi" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOUwX.png">
    <p id="c3hp" data-hp="150"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer maul" style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2 id="c4"></h2>
    <img class="dmaul" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">
    <p id="c4hp" data-hp="180"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="your">
  <h2>Your Character</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="enemies">
  <h2>Enemies</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="fightSection">
  <h2>Fight Section</h2>
  <button id="attack" class="attk">
    <h1>Attack</h1>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="opponent">
  <h2>Opponent</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the most efficient way of producing your desired result, but the smallest number of changes required to your code to get your desired result is to:

- Remove the initial click handlers once the first div is clicked. Do this by using `$('.charContainer').off('click')` once one such div is clicked.
- Move your `$(.foes).on('click', ...` into the original click handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.charContainer').on('click', function() {
    $('.charContainer').off('click'); // *** add this line
    $('#your').append($(this));
    $('.characters>.charContainer').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('charContainer').addClass('foes');
      $('#enemies').append($(this));
    });
    $('.characters').remove();
    $('.foes').on('click', function() { // *** move this into the click handler
      $('#opponent').append($(this));
      $(this).addClass('defender');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="characters">
  <div class="charContainer darth">
    <span>1</span><img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer luke">
    <span>2</span><img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer won">
    <span>3</span><img class="obi" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer maul">
    <span>4</span><img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="your">
  <h2>Your Character</h2>
</div>
<div id="enemies">
  <h2>Enemies</h2>
</div>
<div id="opponent">
  <h2>Opponent</h2>
</div>
```