# Need to append divs back to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE: I solved the problem, but I am not sure why it is working. The problem was that I was creating the reset button in my onlick function for the "attack" button. However, my onlick function for the reset button was outside of the function it was made in. Why does the button not respond when it is outside of the function it was made in?

I have a game where the player chooses from 4 characters and they all have the class name `charContainer`. After the player chooses one character, I iterate over the list using `.each` to remove the class `charContainer` and add class `foes` to each of the characters that didn't get chosen. These characters that get the new `foes` class are appended to a div with id `enemies`. The player then chooses one enemy at a time to fight until either he/she loses all health value or defeats all enemies available.

The problem is, upon one of these conditions being met, I create a button using jquery and give it an id `resetButton`. When that button shows up in the DOM and I click it, I am trying to select all divs with the class `foes` and add class `charContainer` again, and then append it to the original container. This is not working when I click the reset button. In the browser console, it is showing that the class `charContainer` did not get added after the button was clicked.

```
    $('.charContainer').on('click', function(){

    $('#your').append($(this));
    if(firstRound == true) 
    {
        damage = $('#your .charContainer').data('attack');
        playerHP = $('#your .charContainer').data('hpp');
    }

    console.log('before', this);
    $('.characters>.charContainer').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('charContainer').addClass('foes');
        $('#enemies').append($(this));
    })
    if($(this).hasClass('foes'))
    {
        $('#fighter').append($(this));
        console.log('after', this)
        counter = $('#fighter .foes').data('cattack');
        enemyHP = $('#fighter .foes').data('hpp');
    }

    })

    $('#attack').on('click', function(){
    if($('#your .charContainer').length &&  $('#fighter .foes').length)
    {

        playerHP -= counter;
        console.log(playerHP);
        console.log('damage', damage);
        enemyHP -= damage;
        $('.charContainer .health').html(playerHP);
        $('#fighter .foes .health').html(enemyHP); 
        $('.oppName').remove();
        $('.oppName2').remove();
        var newH2 = $('<h2>').addClass('oppName');
        var newH22 = $('<h2>').addClass('oppName2');
        $('.FightProgress').append(newH2);
        $('.FightProgress').append(newH22);
        $('.oppName').html('You attacked ' + $('#fighter .foes').data('name') + ' for ' + damage + ' damage!');
        $('.oppName2').html($('#fighter .foes').data('name') + ' attacked you back for ' + counter + ' damage!');
        damage += 8;
        console.log(enemyHP);
        console.log('cdamage', counter);

        if(playerHP <= 0)
        {
            $('.lose').html(lose);
            var gameReset = $('<button>' + 'Play Again?' + '</button>').attr('id', 'resetButton'); 
            $('.lose').append(gameReset);
        }
        else if(playerHP > 0 && enemyHP <= 0)
        {
            firstRound = false;
            $('#fighter>.foes').hide();
            $('.oppName2').remove();
            $('.oppName').html('You have defeated ' + $('#fighter .foes').data('name') + ' , select another opponent.')
            $('#fighter>.foes').remove();
        }
        }

        })

        $('#resetButton').on('click', function(){
        // $('.characters').append('.charContainer');
        // $('.foes').each(function(){
        $('.foes').addClass('charContainer');
        // $('.characters').append('.charContainer');
        // })
        // if($('#fighter .foes').length == true)
        // {
        //  $('#fighter .foes').addClass('charContainer').removeClass('foes')
        // }
        // $('.characters').append('.charContainer');
        })
```

Comment: I would make an array to store those div elements into an array when the page is loaded, reset methods should then iterate it to put into its original positions.

Comment: to store the div elements in an array, would i just use the selector with the class name? I.E var arr = [$('className')]?, If so, how would the array differentiate between divs if they share a common class name?

Comment: You can create an array which include elements at selector using `.toArray()`, e.g., `$(".className").toArray()`. Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Related [Append divs to another div after its has already been appended to a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077905/append-divs-to-another-div-after-its-has-already-been-appended-to-a-div/)

Comment: call the function which you used to append those elements. (_refresh_)

Comment: I created them in html at first

Answer (score 0):

You can select `"#your > .charContaine, .foes"` use `.appendTo()` to append elements to `.characters` element; `.removeClass()` with `"foes"` as parameter, `.addClass()` with `"charContainer"` as parameter.

Use event delegation as suggested by @Makyen at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078469/) at [Append divs to another div after its has already been appended to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077905/append-divs-to-another-div-after-its-has-already-been-appended-to-a-div/). at `$(document).on('click', '.charContainer:not(#your > .charContainer)'`, `$('#enemies').on('click', ".foes"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click'
  , '.charContainer:not(#your > .charContainer)'
  , function(e) {
    $("#your").append(this);
    $('.characters>.charContainer')
      .each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('charContainer')
          .addClass('foes');
        $('#enemies').append(this);
      })
  })

  $('#enemies').on('click', ".foes", function() {
    $('#opponent').append($(this));
    $(this).addClass('defender');
  });

  $("#resetButton").on("click", function() {
    $("#your > .charContainer, .foes")
      .appendTo(".characters")
      .removeClass("foes")
    .addClass("charContainer")
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="resetButton">
  reset
</button>
<div class="characters">
  <div class="charContainer darth">
    <h2 id="c1"></h2>
    <img class="vade" alt="vader">
    <p id="c1hp" data-hp="120"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer luke">
    <h2 id="c2"></h2>
    <img class="skywalker" alt="luke">
    <p id="c2hp" data-hp="100"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer won">
    <h2 id="c3"></h2>
    <img class="obi" alt="obiwan">
    <p id="c3hp" data-hp="150"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="charContainer maul">
    <h2 id="c4"></h2>
    <img class="dmaul" alt="maul">
    <p id="c4hp" data-hp="180"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="your">
  <h2>Your Character</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="enemies">
  <h2>Enemies</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
<div id="fightSection">
  <h2>Fight Section</h2>
  <button id="attack" class="attk">
    <h1>Attack</h1>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="opponent">
  <h2>Opponent</h2>
  <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
</div>
```

Comment: What does the:  , .foes do in "#your > .charContaine, .foes"

Comment: `"#your > .charContainer, .foes"` selects `.charContainer` elements that are child elements of `#your` parent element. Comma  `,` between selectors allows additional selectors to be added to resulting element collection, here `.foes` elements are included. See [Selectors - 5.2.1 Grouping](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping)

Comment: Cool, did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do something like this:

Working Fiddle : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/Ls3hxbcb/6/)

```
$('.foes').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('foes').addClass('charContainer');
        //part where you add them back to original container
        $(this).appendTo('.orginalContainerClass');
});
```

You have to iterate each element with `foes` class and then remove `foes` class and add `charContainer` class on click of `resetButton`.

I hoe it will help.